# DocuSign API - Connect Existing USERS/Accounts

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

In a few words: how do existing organizations access an API connection integrated in an app?

Background info: the question comes when creating an app for say B2C companies to send envelopes/templates with their DocuSign subscription. Truly EVERYTHING was looked into - all documentation, the sandbox, pricing pages and happen to not find an answer.

It appears the only solution here is serving an existing client is under a separate "sub account" within their organization account. That would defeat the objectives and comes with real drawbacks in terms of usability.

That aside, APP creators would have to purchase and subscribe to an API plan for a connection and pay for credits they wouldn't use.

How is this handled? A spec issue or perhaps impossible?

Best

Answer (score 0):

did you look into [becoming a partner](https://partners.docusign.com/s/)? partners have reseller model, where you have your partner account, but then you sell DocuSign and have semi-management capabilities for the accounts you sell to. You don't have full access to them, but just what you need (you can't for example see their envelopes etc.)

https://www.docusign.com/company/terms-and-conditions/reseller

Comment: Suggest further discussion directly with the partner/reseller team of DocuSign. Not sure further help can be provided in Stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you. Under the reseller model existing account holders would be impossible to serve. Sounds interesting for several cases and you guys are true leaders - I’m afraid for an early stage company these entry level fixed commitments are really steep. With that coming on top of a mandatory subscription to an "Intermediate API package" per user, wonder how this could be a viable option. It sounds like from the technical side, the API capabilities allow for a case different to that Subaccount setup with new users